# Spring RequestMapping parameter custom annotation

Tags: spring, annotations

in my web application I have many places where I need to retrieve current logged account (from session).

```
Account account = getAccountFromSession(session);
```

This piece of code is repeated many many times. I wonder if this is possible to make my request look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSomething(
        @RequestParam String someParam,
        @Account Account account) { ... }
```

where @Account is my custom annotation.

How can I tell spring to process this annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) (or [`WebArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) for versions below 3.1).

To enable your argument resolver:

- If you use `@EnableWebMvc` - make your `@Configuration` implement `WebMvcConfigurer` and override `addArgumentResolvers()`
- If you use `<mvc:annotation-driven>` - use `argument-resolvers` attribute
- For older versions you may need to declare `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` manually and set its `customArgumentResolvers`